# Snowflake Native SSO through Okta - "Failed to connect to okta. Error code=401"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have cloned [Snowflake-connector-net](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net) source code and made a TestApp where I'm testing authenticators. I'm stuck with **Native SSO through Okta** - I get the following message:
*Snowflake Internal Error: Unable to connect. One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).)*
Here's the code snippet with the ConnectionString. Please point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())

    try
    {
      conn.ConnectionString = "account=[mySnowflakeAccount];authenticator=https://[companyName].okta.com;user=[myOktaAccount];password=[myOktaPassword];port=443;connection timeout=0";

      conn.Open();
      conn.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("Success");

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    };

  Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: 1. Are you able to login to Okta using same details (URL/USER/PASS) and a browser? 2. Does your account includes additional details like region/cloud provider? 3. Are you using a proxy in between?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

1.Yes;
2.I've connected my Okta account with Snowflake application and have been using it successfully for 'externalbrowser' auth;
3.No

Comment: Do you by any chance has Okta+MFA enabled? If yes, that possibly could be a reason for this error. Having said that the stack error is not quite pointing to that.

Comment: The connection format provided in github for native SSO is as follows: 
conn.ConnectionString = "account=testaccount;authenticator={okta_url_endpoint};user={login_name_for_IdP};db=testdb;schema=testschema";

There is no port mentioned in it as what you have shown in the provided sample.

Comment: @SrinathMenon, I don't have MFA enabled. The same message appears when I leave out port or connection timeout from the ConnectionString. However, if I don't type a password (which isn't required in the github example) then I get "Required property PASSWORD is not provided."

Comment: Would you be able to use Snowsql from the host where this test is failing and run with native okta authentication? This would give some details if it's related to some firewall or if it's a connector related issue.

Comment: Yes, the problem persists. I get:
"250001 (08004): Failed to get authentication by OKTA: 401: Unauthorized"

Is there a channel where I can send you logfile?

Comment: @VukVulicevic was there a resolution?